# Download file, open new tab in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

After some actions on my site user can donwload file. First, I ask user: "Would you like to download file". This is modal dialog created with fancybox. There are buttons: Yes and No. When user clicks "Yes" I want to open new tab in browser and show standart save file dialog.
I have this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#agentAcceptSave', function () {
        alert(1);
        window.open = '/ticket?orderId=' + $('#agentOrderId').val();
}
```

But, new tab not open and url not calls, but alert is showed.
Where is a error?

Comment: Could you post the whole code in jsfiddle?

Comment: How? Files generated in `/ticket` action.

Comment: `open` is a method not a property. `open()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I tried this code and it worked for me:

```
$(document).on('click', '#download', function() {  
    window.open('http://www.google.com');    
});
```